Chemical odor after painting the ceiling of the bathroom to deal with the mold
This is my first time posting here, so I appreciate that you point it out if anything is inappropriate.
There has been mold on the ceiling of our bathroom in an apartment building. It does not look like rapidly expanding, but recently we finally decided to clean it up. We told the maintenance team of the building that there was mold and please came to clean it. We were not in the apartment when they came. It seems that at least they have repainted the ceiling, not sure whether or how they cleaned the original mold.
Here is the problem. There has been a chemical odor in our bathroom after painting on the same day (on the morning of the painting day there was no such odor), but the team insisted that they use water-based paint, and it should not smell like that. They also paint other units, and nobody complains. It has been ten days now and we are still trying to identify the source of the odor.
What do you think the odor comes from? I think it is a chemical odor that is a little pungent, and it is not an earthy smell or a sewer smell. The team think it is different from paint smell. Another feature of the smell is that it becomes stronger and stronger if I turn on the hot shower for a while. So it might be sensitive to the rise of temperature.
There is no visible damped area on the ceiling or the wall. I tried to fan at the door of the bathroom for a whole day but the smell persists.
It has been quite mysterious and annoying. Thank you very much!
UPDATE: The painter says the black stain on the ceiling is not mold but just moisture (which sounds ridiculous but anyway). The procedure was, they scrape it, use cover stain primer, and Benjamin moore semi gloss atrium white paint.

how much time between mold treatment and the paint job

@Traveler
I am actually not sure whether they treat the mold or not. The whole thing was completed in one day and I only know a painter was involved. I will definitely ask the manager to check that, but I suspect that the painter just scraped the original black mold on the ceiling and did the painting.

I suspect they did spray, but then did not wait long enough and just painted over it, and that is the smell

@Traveler In that case, what do you think I can do to remove the odor? And is that odor harmful to health?

it depends on what chemical they used to kill the mold, since it is sealed by paint it will take long time to outgas, you can try hairdryer to speed up process, you could also scrape the paint and let it dry for few days, Using mold removal sprays can cause adverse health effects,

Is there and exhaust fan in the bath?  If so turn it on and let it run.  If you have a  window, open it.

@Traveler Thank you a lot! The super said they use Clorox spray to remove the mold and he says the smell is not like Clorox (I am not sure what Clorox product they use exactly but the odor does not have a "fresh smell" as in cleaning products).

@RMDman There is a vent but no exhaust fan to turn on. And it also does not have window. I tried to put a standing fan at the door when taking a shower and leave the door open, that helps a bit (might be because the temperature is lower compared to not doing all of these, and the odor is indeed very temperature sensitive), but there is still odor.

@Traveler Here is another clue (not sure whether it is helpful): if I put my nose at the wall or closer to the ceiling (with a ladder), the smell does not get stronger. The smell is strongest in the middle of the bathroom. If the odor is caused by mold spray sealed by paint, will I smell a stronger odor when I get closer to the wall? Or is this way not practical to distinguish to source? Thanks a lot!

@Traveler Sorry to bother you again. I think your conjecture is very reasonable in logic, but I still have some confusion after experimenting more with it. The odor does not have the same smell as the mold spray -- the odor has a more "paint-like" tone and is more pungent. Second, I tried to use hairdryer to blow the ceiling and the walls in the bathroom. My guess before was that this should produce strong odor. But it does not. From my nose, I feel the odor does not change much after blowing the ceiling and walls for 12minutes. I focus on a small area for ~1min and then move to a nearby area.

I had that problem once with no waiting long enough for primer to dry and painting over it, on a cabinet. do you know what paint was used

@Traveler Thank you so much. Today I asked the painter directly, not the super. The painter told me (he thinks) the black stain on the ceiling is not mold. Their procedure was scraping the ceiling, then using cover stain primer and Benjamin moore semi gloss atrium white paint. No spray was used.

Now we believe that the odor comes from the oil-based primer, which is Cover Stain primer.
The whole procedure has a lot of misinformation which obscures the truth... which shows the importance of communications with the vendors.
Thank everyone for your helpful comments!

You always need to ventilate after painting. Open windows and doors and put a fan in. If you think a rise in temp increases it then put a heater in an alternating pattern.
